# Is it possible to use the facebook sdk for php in a WAMP environment?

Tags: php, windows, facebook

The instructions here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ seem to me to be directed to the Linux environment.

Is it possible to access this SDK from an application developped in a WAMP environment?

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible to use the Facebook SDK on WAMP.

In fact, I can't find any reference in their documentation that speaks of Linux. The "Getting Started' installation step directs to https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk, which says to install the SDK through Composer. As Composer is [available on Windows](https://getcomposer.org/download/), and you can run PHP on Windows, I don't see anything that would prevent you from running the Facebook SDK through WAMP. Just make sure to run Composer from your WAMP's project folder.

Comment: Is it nescesarily to install composer?

Comment: Composer is what initially led me to think this will be limited to unix only. I saw since, that composer is available on windows as well

Comment: Composer's the easiest way to install it, but it's not strictly required.